# There's a way to export my logs from watson assistant at once (more than 100 each time)?

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I am using the command

curl -u "apikey:{apikey}" "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/assistant/api/v1/workspaces/{workspace_id}/logs?version=2019-02-28"

to request the exportation of the list of logs of Watson Assistant, and it is returning 100 each time. I do the subsequent requests with next_url but after some calls it stops to work (after 20 or 30). Anybody knows how to increase the page size? Or if there are a tool to help me to export all list of logs? I have more than 32k messages to export and I am not an IT person (I am an accountant).

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation ( https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant/assistant-v1#list-log-events-in-all-workspaces ), to get more logs per page, one needs to increase `page_limit` that is set to `100` by default. E.g.

`curl -u "apikey:{apikey}" "https://{icp_cluster_host}/assistant/api/v1/workspaces?version=2018-09-20&page_limit=200"` ...